# How can I convert a matrix into matlab form string?

Tags: string-manipulation, data, matlink

How can I convert a matrix into matlab form?

```
matrix2Matlab[matrix0_] :=  Module[{matrix = matrix0},   "[" <> StringReplace[    ExportString[matrix, "CSV"], {"\n" -> ";", "," -> " "}] <> "]"]

matrix2Matlab[m = IdentityMatrix[3]]

(*
    [1 0 0;0 1 0;0 0 1]
*)
```

Are there more simpler ways?

I use MATLink to deal with the string matrix.

Comment: You need the `ToMatlab` package... See my answer in the linked question for details on obtaining the package and using it. For your case, all you need to do is `ToMatlab@IdentityMatrix@3`. However, if you're using MATLink, you don't need to do any of this... could you perhaps clarify your usage? You can transfer to MATLAB using `MSet["mat", IdentityMatrix@3]`...

Comment: @rm-rf Hi, do you know how to MSet a matrixList like here what the MEvaluate do? `matrixList={IdentityMatrix[3],Partition[Range[9],3]};
MATLink`MEvaluate@"m = [ 1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]; 
       m(:,:,2) = [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9;]";`

Comment: @user92733 What kind of data structure are you expecting on the MATLAB side?  `matrixList` here is really a 3D array, so that's what you get with `MSet["s", matrixList]`.  If you want to treat it as a list of two matrices, you can represent it as a cell which contains two 3x3 matrices and transfer it using `MSet["c", MCell[matrixList]]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Hi, the expected result on the Matlab side is shown by `MATLinkMEvaluate@"m = [ 1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]; m(:,:,2) = [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9;]";`

Comment: @user92733 That's just a transposition away from what `MSet[..., matrixList]` gives you, isn't it?

Comment: @Szabolcs How to transpose? I've tried `Transpose@matrixList and Transpose/@matrixList`

Comment: @user92733 In Mathematica, use the second argument of `Transpose` to achieve the proper permutation of the dimensions.  Check the documentation for details please.  In MATLAB the analogous function is called `permute`.  Also note that while MATLAB prints `m(:,:,1)` and `m(:,:,2)`, the matrices can be obtained by `m(1,:,:)` and `m(2,:,:)` *without* any transposition needed.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks, I hope this will speed up my codes. I seldom use the second argument of `Transpose`.